# Gah!! Error 424 runtime error : Object required Word Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-word, runtime-error, variable-assignment

Im trying to load the contents of a textfile into a variable but I get the titular error, searching the VBA knowledgebase led me to belive that

```
Set mySQL = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\sql_query_temp.res")
```

Would solve it but that just produces 'Error : Object Required' when I run. Heres my code, what have I missed?

```
'Requires Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x library in references
Public Sub ConnectToOdbc()

    Dim myconn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim myrs As New Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String
    Dim myrows As Long

    'Open file containing SQL query
    mySQL = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\sql_query_temp.res") <----- bad!

    'Open Connection
     myconn.Open "DSN=database"

    'Do Query
     myrs.Source = mySQL
     Set myrs.ActiveConnection = myconn
     myrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
     myrs.Open

     'Count Rows
      myrows = myrs.RecordCount

      'Add text to word document!
      Selection.TypeText (myrows)

      'Close Connection
      myrs.Close
      myconn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: `My.Computer` is VB.NET which is entirely different from `VBA`

Comment: Thanks, I have no experience of VB in any form whatsoever, It would have taken me a long time to find that out. I'll be more careful in future.

Comment: WTH, Microsoft? This exact method (My...ReadAllText) worked for me last week and now it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`My.Computer` is VB.NET which is entirely different from `VBA` instead you can;

```
Function readFile(path As String) As String
    Dim hF As Integer
    hF = FreeFile()
    Open path For Input As #hF
        readFile = Input$(LOF(hF), #hF)
    Close #hF
End Function

...

mySQL = readFile("C:\sql_query_temp.res")
```

Comment: Many thanks, worked first time and was clear and concise, I presume that the '#' is a bit like a pointer?

Comment: When a # is in-front of a variable it indicates the variable is a file handle (from FreeFile) iirc that the only time you see #varname. (varname# is different and indicates varname is of type Double)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

It will allow you to search any given directory rather than fixating on just the one. This directory is then placed onto the variable 'inFileName'

`inFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text & r01 Files(*.*),*.*", , "Open Neutral File", "OPEN)`

Hope this helps.